# Why doesn't the USCIS offer premium processing for all its immigration forms?

Tags: united-states, immigration, uscis

Premium processing is [available on only certain USCIS immigration forms](https://www.uscis.gov/forms/all-forms/how-do-i-request-premium-processing) and not all USCIS immigration forms.  Why doesn't the USCIS offer premium processing for all its immigration forms?

Since the USCIS collect additional fees for premium processing, I would have guessed that they offer premium processing for all its immigration forms.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which immigration forms do not allow premium processing? My guess is that here we are talking about immigrants who are already employed (or have a job offer) from a US employer, so long processing may actually disrupt an activity in the US. Also, frequently it is the employer who pays the processing fee (although the applicants can do it themselves).

Comment: @RogerVadim eg Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization).

Comment: @RogerVadim permanent resident status does not expire, but the green card document does -- they are valid for 10 years.  Someone who is eligible for naturalization might want to speed up the process to avoid having to apply for a new green card (I believe it's necessary to have a valid green card when naturalizing, but I'm by no means certain of that).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135912/discussion-between-phoog-and-roger-vadim).

Comment: Do you want me to migrate to [Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)? It got a flag suggesting that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JJJ thanks, I think it's preferable to keep it here as expats SE doesn't focus on politics / governmental decisions.

Comment: Similar question was asked on Expatriates.SE: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24110/why-is-premium-processing-available-on-only-certain-uscis-immigration-forms-and

Comment: @user102008 thanks, correct, it focused on the legal reason. Here I'm asking why such a law/regulation.